Missing Data in experiments, MIPO, MIPO|X vs MCAR, MAR, MNAR
Hello I was reading Field Experiments by Alan Gerber and Donald Green and was introduced to the idea of missingness independent of potential outcomes (MIPO). And MIPO|X which is missingness independent when you condition on covariates. Most of my education on missingness has been about Missing completely at random (MCAR), Missing at random(MAR), Missing not at random(MNAR) and whether or not to impute.
MIPO is defined as
$$
Y_i(z) \perp\!\!\!\!\perp R_i(z)
$$
MIPO|X is defined as
$$
\{Y_i(z) \perp\!\!\!\!\perp R_i(z)\}|\mathbf{X}_i = \mathbf{x} \text{ for all }  \mathbf{x}
$$
$R_i(z)$ is the potential response for the outcome with treatment $z$.
$Y_i(z)$ is the potential outcome with treatment $z$
From what I can tell MIPO is focused on whether or not a treatment effect is unbiased or still causally defensible and MCAR, MAR, MNAR is more about if inferences can be made back to a full sample without missingness is that correct?
I was curious about how the different lines of thinking impacts analysis and where the ideas came from for further reading?

I'm not familiar with MIPA or MIPO|X.  For my benefit, can you provide mathematical definitions of these terms?

Added @Galen, the notation comes from Gerber and Green Field experiment book. Not sure where it originally was developed.

Please define all acronyms.
